# Build webpack on travis ci

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, yarnpkg

I want run webpack build for production via this command:

```
"prod": "webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js"
```

My `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.9.1"

install:
  - npm i -g yarn && yarn

before_script:
  - yarn prod

deploy:
  provider: s3
  local-dir: public
  on:
    branch: cloudfront
```

But this script don't load right file, and on prod site I see `ENV=dev`

I'm also tried these commands:

`before_deploy`

`script`

But it didn't help

webpack.production.config.js:

```
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  filename: 'index.js',
  publicPath: '/'
},
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
 'process.env': {
   'BASE_URL': JSON.stringify('url'),
   'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
 }
})
```

travis.log:

```
The command "npm test" exited with 0.
before_deploy
9.54s$ webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js
Hash: 4aa1139f3ef3381f91ec
Version: webpack 1.13.2
Time: 9133ms
       Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
    index.js     176 kB       0  [emitted]  main
index.js.map  151 bytes       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 255 hidden modules
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
dpl.3
Deploying application
uploading "index.html" with {:content_type=>"text/html"}
uploading "index.js.map" with {:content_type=>""}
uploading "index.js" with {:content_type=>"application/javascript"}
# HEAD detached at 8a81ecb
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   public/index.js
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (593621bc433e8223b3b5c32751122c23297b202e)
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need add this line to .travis.yml:

```
skip_cleanup: true
```

It's helped me

Answer (score 0):

Even though your web pack is producing a bundle for production, that doesn't change the environment on your server. Where is ENV being set?

Comment: in webpack files, in `new webpack.DefinePlugin({`. If I run this command on local machine, all works fine

Comment: Webpack only sets the "environment" for when it's building your bundle.js. When running on your server the environment may be anything the server wants. So when it serves your app, if it sets ENV to dev then that's what your environment will show.

Comment: I making build on ci, with `-p` parameter, so in config for production I set this variable

Comment: can you show where it says ENV is dev? Are you just logging that to console or something?

Comment: [link](http://spafront2016.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html), in console. The problem is that it takes build from repo, not what did ci

Comment: Yes that's correct. The repo will be pulled and built on the server. The ENV vars must be set on your server if you are building on your server.